# How to upload a file with scalajs-react and AJAX

Tags: ajax, scalajs-react

I want to send a file with Scalajs-react and Ajax.  The sending part is easy with `Ajax.send(requestBody: js.Any)` method in the `onSubmit` method of my `form` (which I took care to stop the event propagation with `preventDefault`). To build the request body I use `FormData(event.target)`.

```
def f(e: ReactFormEvent) = {
          Ajax
            .post("http://localhost:9000/rpc/v1/test/update-dataset")
            .setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
            .send({
              new FormData(
                e.target
                  .asInstanceOf[dom.raw.HTMLFormElement]
              )
            })
            .validateStatusIs(200)(Callback.throwException)
            .asCallback
        }
Form(onSubmit = e => f(e) >> e.preventDefaultCB)(
          FormGroup("groupInput")(
            FormFile(label = "Input")(),
            UncontrolledFormControl(ref = ref, defaultValue = "abc")()
          ),
          Button(`type` = "submit")("Submit")
        )
```

Looks good, but for some reason the request body does not contain anything (ex: `------WebKitFormBoundaryAnYzDUdxWxA8hrJR--`) as if `FormData` did not manage to retrieve the data from the form.
Here is a printout of the two children of `e.target` where we can see that both inputs have a non-empty `value`:

```
__reactFiber$ipxb5pt9wbi,[object Object],__reactProps$ipxb5pt9wbi,[object Object],_wrapperState,[object Object],__reactEvents$ipxb5pt9wbi,[object Set],value,C:\fakepath\artifacts.zip,_valueTracker,[object Object]
__reactFiber$ipxb5pt9wbi,[object Object],__reactProps$ipxb5pt9wbi,[object Object],_wrapperState,[object Object],__reactEvents$ipxb5pt9wbi,[object Set],value,abc,_valueTracker,[object Object]
```

Note: When I manually `append` items to the `FormData`, there are present in the body request.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why `new FormData(formElement)` isn't working, but building manually the FormData works. Ex:

```
send{
  val fd = new FormData()
  val elem = dom.document
                .getElementById("form-inputf")
                .asInstanceOf[HTMLInputElement]
  fd.append("file", elem.files(0))
  fd
}
```

If only one file needs to be send, one doesn't even need to use `FormData` at all. Simply relying on the File API is enough. Ex:

```
send{
val elem = dom.document
                .getElementById("form-inputf")
                .asInstanceOf[HTMLInputElement]
elem.files(0)
}
```